# Why is the second rect moving before the first one in my snake game

Tags: javascript, html

So Im very new to JavaScript and I'm still learning, in my code I would really like to understand why the tail of my snake is moving before the head, shouldn't the head's x increase before the tail's
Since the increment code for head is before
The tail. What I'm trying to achieve is to have the x increment then the head moves and as it moves the snakex array value gets replaced by velocity which now makes the tail's x increase but maintain a distance from the head's starting position so as not to overlap with the head

```js
var canvas= document.querySelector("canvas");
var right=document.querySelector("#right");
var left=document.querySelector("#left");
var up=document.querySelector("#up");
var down=document.querySelector("#down");

canvas.width=window.innerWidth;
canvas.height=window.innerHeight-500;
var ctx= canvas.getContext("2d");

width= 20;
height=20;

var x=40;
var tx=x-20;
var y=0;
var sx;
var sy;
var inc=0;
var change=true;
var speed = 0;
var velocity;
var snakex=[x]
var snakey=[y]
var motionx;


setInterval(function move(){
ctx.fillStyle="white";
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
ctx.fillStyle="orange";

x+=20;
ctx.fillRect(snakex[0],snakey[0],20,20);

velocity=x-20;
snakex.splice(0,1, velocity);

ctx.strokeStyle="green";
ctx.strokeRect(velocity,snakey[0],20,20);


},200)

function sright(){
   
}

right.addEventListener("click", sright);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>snake</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
<body>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <button id="right">right</button>
    <button id="down">down</button>
    <button id="left">left</button>
    <button id="up">up</button>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The reason why the tail is moving before the head is because the code for the head is inside the setInterval function. The setInterval function is a loop that runs every 200 milliseconds, so the code inside the loop is executed every 200 milliseconds. The code for the tail is outside the setInterval function, so it is only executed once when the page is loaded. Therefore, the tail is moving before the head because the code for the head is inside the loop and the code for the tail is outside the loop.

Comment: Thks for answering,I'm not sure thats quite right could you show me a snippet of the code you think is for the head and a snippet of the code for the tail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a fixed version of the code.
However, if you want your snake to grow and have more than 1 block in size, you will need to change the approach.

On each iteration, you will need to copy snake blocks from tail to head like so:

```
for (let index=snakeLength-2; index>=0; index --) {
  snakex[index + 1] = snakex[index];
  snakey[index + 1] = snakey[index];
}
```

This will guarantee that the snake's body moves. After this move, you can update snakex[0] and snakey[0] based on the user's input. This will allow a user to control the snake's head.

Please let me know if this helps.

```js
var canvas= document.querySelector("canvas");
var right=document.querySelector("#right");
var left=document.querySelector("#left");
var up=document.querySelector("#up");
var down=document.querySelector("#down");

canvas.width=window.innerWidth;
canvas.height=window.innerHeight-500;
var ctx= canvas.getContext("2d");

width= 20;
height=20;

var x=40;
var tx=x-20;
var y=0;
var sx;
var sy;
var inc=0;
var change=true;
var speed = 0;
var velocity;
var snakex=[x]
var snakey=[y]
var motionx;


setInterval(function move(){
ctx.fillStyle="white";
ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
ctx.fillStyle="orange";

// x+=20;
// here you need to update snakex[0] instead of x
// to make sure that the next execution of the method move
// will reuse it
snakex[0] = snakex[0] + 20;
ctx.fillRect(snakex[0],snakey[0],20,20);

// the tail should always be calculated based on the head
velocity=snakex[0]-20;
// the next line removes snakex[0] that was updated, you don't need this
// snakex.splice(0,1, velocity);

ctx.strokeStyle="green";
ctx.strokeRect(velocity,snakey[0],20,20);


},200)

function sright(){
   
}

right.addEventListener("click", sright);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>snake</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
<body>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <button id="right">right</button>
    <button id="down">down</button>
    <button id="left">left</button>
    <button id="up">up</button>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Was my answer helpful to you? Is there anything else I can help you with?

Comment: Yes, Thks bro it worked although I made some personal changes

Comment: @EdwinChigozie, awesome! Happy to hear. Would you mind picking my answer as the solution?

Comment: But I have a problem now. Could you help me with this question here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75266987/alternative-to-using-an-event-in-a-setinterval

Comment: @EdwinChigozie this answer is correct and I would recommend the same https://stackoverflow.com/a/75270874/3317161