# Alternative to using an event in a setinterval

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So I tried my code and I ain't getting the results I expect, especially with the function `btnr`. Basically what I'm trying to achieve is this: as the code is running I want the snake to change direction when the button is clicked.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var right = document.querySelector("#right");
var left = document.querySelector("#left");
var up = document.querySelector("#up");
var down = document.querySelector("#down");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 200;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

width = 20;
height = 20;

var snake = [{
  x: 40,
  y: 0
}, {
  x: 20,
  y: 0
}];

function move() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  for (var i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    //lets just say i stands for index number
    ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
    ctx.strokeRect(snake[i].x, snake[i].y, width, height);
  }

  snakex = snake[0].x;
  snakey = snake[0].y;
  snakex += 20;

  function btnr() {
    snakex -= 20;
  }
  right.addEventListener("click", btnr);

  var newhead = {
    x: snakex,
    y: snakey
  };
  snake.pop();
  snake.unshift(newhead);
}

setInterval(move, 800);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<button id="right">right</button>
<button id="down">down</button>
<button id="left">left</button>
<button id="up">up</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've adjusted the code to make the buttons respond as you expect:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const right = document.querySelector("#right");
const left = document.querySelector("#left");
const up = document.querySelector("#up");
const down = document.querySelector("#down");

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 200;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const width = 20;
const height = 20;

const snake = [{
  x: 40,
  y: 0
}, {
  x: 20,
  y: 0
}];

// --- NEW --- //
let direction = 'right'

right.addEventListener("click", () => direction = 'right');
left.addEventListener("click", () => direction = 'left');
up.addEventListener("click", () => direction = 'up');
down.addEventListener("click", () => direction = 'down');

function move() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
  for (let i = 0; i < snake.length; i++) {
    //lets just say i stands for index number
    ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
    ctx.strokeRect(snake[i].x, snake[i].y, width, height);
  }

  let snakex = snake[0].x;
  let snakey = snake[0].y;

  // --- NEW --- //
  if (direction === 'right') {
    snakex += 20;
  } else if (direction === 'left') {
    snakex -= 20;
  } else if (direction === 'up') {
    snakey -= 20;
  } else if (direction === 'down') {
    snakey += 20;
  }

  const newhead = {
    x: snakex,
    y: snakey
  };

  snake.pop();
  snake.unshift(newhead);
}

setInterval(move, 800);
```

```css
:root {
  background-color: #242424;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <canvas></canvas>
  <button id="right">right</button>
  <button id="down">down</button>
  <button id="left">left</button>
  <button id="up">up</button>
</div>
```

The main concept you were missing is that you need some way to to track what direction the snake is going. To do that, we can create a variable `direction` and set it to a string that represents the snake's direction.

After that, we can hook up the buttons to change the direction when each button is pressed by setting the `direction` variable to `left`, `right`, `up`, or `down` depending on what was pressed. I moved the logic to add these handles out of your event loop because it would add a new handler each time, which is unnecessary.

Finally in the event loop itself we have some logic to check which direction is pressed, and we adjust the snake's location accordingly.